# Android studio не видит KVM акселератор виртуализации (Ubuntu)

Tags: android-sdk, kvm

Android Vitrual Device Manager из Andriod studio не понимает, что мой процессор поддерживает витруализацию (Intel Core i5), и что в системе тоже есть всё необходимое, и почему-то не даёт запустить эмулятор устройства.

В биосе виртуализация точно включена.

KVM установил согласно инструкции - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation. Команда kvm-ok выдаёт то, что требуется (KVM can by used).

Проверил все инструкции в гугле. Добавил своего юзера в группы:
$ sudo adduser your_user_name kvm
$ sudo adduser your_user_name libvirtd
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но.
В списке устройств написано "HAXM requires a Genuine Intel processor". См скрин. Хотя я знаю, что в линуксе вместо HAXM нужен KVM, который установлен и настроен. Что не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `kvm-ok` проверяет только совместимость `CPU`, но не правильность установки `KVM`. Для этого ваша инструкция советует использовать `virsh list --all`

Comment: я всё пробовал, и это тоже. Эта команда выводила всё так как и положено по инструкции, но не спасало. Скрин сделать не могу, потому что уже грохнул линукс. Работать в нём это мазахизм. Большую часть времени решать всякие проблемы и искать хоть немного рабочее по это не моё )

Comment: У меня виртуализация в биосе была включена тоже. Нашел ответ на англ версии сайта, помогла установка доп пакета KVM (название пакета не помню).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, никто не смог помочь, но решение проблемы оказалось довольно простым.
Нужно установить Windows и радоваться всем тем безграничным возможностям, что там есть. Тут тебе и стандартный эмулятор отлично работает, и с десяток альтернативных, в т.ч. классный Genymotion. Всё устанавливается за секунды, не требует часов на настройку.

Линуксы для сколь-нибудь серьёзной работы не годятся, так, посёрфить в нете только. Я даже быстро набросал длинный сравнительный список. Если кому интересно - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y8BvCVaTgauWnTA6Uhamgj5oNuNibo9OPethFaVOBQ0/edit?usp=sharing